# sbt-native-packager fails with "Too many open files in system" when mapping a directory

Tags: java, scala, jvm, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have an sbt-based project. Universal packaging plugin is enabled with

```
.enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

and additional directories are mapped like this:

```
mappings in Universal ++= directory("public")
```

I tried to build the package with **dist** command on multiple machines (running OS X and Linux) it always fails with the following trace:

```
    Could not create file [...omitted...]/target/streams/compile/$global/$global/discoveredMainClasses/datajava.io.IOException: Too many open files in system
            at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
            at sbt.IO$.touch(IO.scala:196)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:129)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.binary(Streams.scala:116)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$persist$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:27)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$persist$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:26)
            at sbt.std.Streams$class.use(Streams.scala:75)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3.use(Streams.scala:100)
            at sbt.SessionVar$.persist(SessionVar.scala:26)
            at sbt.SessionVar$.persistAndSet(SessionVar.scala:21)
            at sbt.Project$RichTaskSessionVar$$anonfun$storeAs$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Project.scala:563)
            at sbt.Project$RichTaskSessionVar$$anonfun$storeAs$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Project.scala:563)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:40)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:40)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
            at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:138)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:105)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.applyResults(EvaluateTask.scala:387)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.liftedTree1$1(EvaluateTask.scala:361)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:358)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:378)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:64)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:62)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:314)
            at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:62)
            at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:71)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:32)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:31)
            at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
            at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:153)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:152)
            at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:244)
            at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:241)
            at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
            at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
            at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:54)
            at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files in system
            at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
            at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
            at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(IO.scala:196)
            at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(IO.scala:196)
            at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(IO.scala:196)
            at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
            at sbt.IO$.touch(IO.scala:196)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:129)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.binary(Streams.scala:116)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$persist$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:27)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$persist$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:26)
            at sbt.std.Streams$class.use(Streams.scala:75)
            at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3.use(Streams.scala:100)
            at sbt.SessionVar$.persist(SessionVar.scala:26)
            at sbt.SessionVar$.persistAndSet(SessionVar.scala:21)
            at sbt.Project$RichTaskSessionVar$$anonfun$storeAs$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Project.scala:563)
            at sbt.Project$RichTaskSessionVar$$anonfun$storeAs$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Project.scala:563)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:40)
            at sbt.SessionVar$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SessionVar.scala:40)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
            at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
            at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:138)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:105)
            at scala.Function$$anonfun$chain$1.apply(Function.scala:24)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.applyResults(EvaluateTask.scala:387)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.liftedTree1$1(EvaluateTask.scala:361)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:358)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:378)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:64)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:62)
            at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:314)
            at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:62)
            at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:71)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:32)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:31)
            at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
            at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:153)
            at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:152)
            at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:244)
            at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:241)
            at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
            at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
            at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
            at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
            at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:54)
            at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
            at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
            at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    [error] Could not create file [...omitted...]/target/streams/compile/$global/$global/discoveredMainClasses/datajava.io.IOException: Too man
    y open files in system
    [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Passing `-XX:-MaxFDLimit` option to JVM didn't do any difference.

The version of sbt is 0.13.9, sbt-native-packager is 1.1.1 (latest, also used v1.0.6).

So it this a bug or I just have to many files in that directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see you have some problems with underlying opertaion system:

> ```
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files in system
>         at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
> ```

Try to tweak max allowed open files settings in Linux. For example [here](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/) are some commands:

> If you are getting error
>   “Too many open files (24)” then your application/command/script is
>   hitting max open file limit allowed by linux. You need to increase
>   open file limit as below:
>
> Increase limit Per-User Limit
>
> Open
>   file: `/etc/security/limits.conf`
>
> Paste
>   following towards end:
>
> ```
> *
>
> hard    nofile      500000
> *         soft    nofile      500000 root      hard    nofile      500000 root      soft    nofile      500000
> ```
>
> 500000 is
>   fair number. I am not sure what is max limit but 999999 (Six-9) worked
>   for me once as far as I remember.
>
> Once you save file, you may
>   need to logout and login again.
>
> pam-limits
>
> I read at many places
>   that an extra step is neede for limit to change for daemon processes.
>   I did not need following yet, but if above changes are not working for
>   you, you may give this a try.
>
> Open `/etc/pam.d/common-session`
>
> Add
>   following line:
>
> ```
> session required
> pam_limits.so
> ```
>
> System-Wide Limit
>
> Set this higher
>   than user-limit set above.
>
> Open `/etc/sysctl.conf`
>
> Add
>   following:
>
> ```
> fs.file-max =
> 2097152
> ```
>
> Run:
>
> ```
> sysctl -p
> ```
>
> Above will increase
>   “total” number of files that can remain open system-wide.
>
> Verify New Limits
>
> Use following command to see max limit of file descriptors:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
> ```
>
> Hard Limit
>
> ```
> ulimit
> -Hn
> ```
>
> Soft Limit
>
> ```
> ulimit -Sn
> ```
>
> if you are logged in
>   as root:
>
> Check limit for other user
>
> Just
>   replace `www-data` by linux username you wish to check
>   limits for:
>
> ```
> su - www-data -c
> 'ulimit -aHS' -s '/bin/bash'
> ```
>
> Check limits of a running process:
>
> Find process-id (PID):
>
> ```
> ps aux |
> grep process-name
> ```
>
> Suppose, XXX is PID, then run
>   following commands to check limits:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/XXX/limits
> ```